# What is meany by point of oscillation and how is it difference from point of suspension ? Is both are intechangable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

Is O' is the point of oscillation ?

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The point of oscillation in a compound pendulum with centre of mass at C, and suspended from a point $A$, is the point B on the line AC such that if all the mass of the pendulum were concentrated at B then a simple pendulum of length $|{\rm AB}|$ would have the same period.  Thus AB is the effective length of the compound pendulum.